# How can I add bcryptjs to this code to encrypt passwords?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, nodemon, bcryptjs

Sorry but `enter code here`I can't make mongo database shows me the passwords encrypted and when I changed directly from the body the login doesn't work. How can I modify this code to encrypt passwords with bcryptjs?

```js
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var {client,dbName} = require('../db/mongo');
var passport = require('passport');
var LocalStrategy = require('passport-local');

const bcryptjs = require("bcryptjs");



passport.use(new LocalStrategy(
  async function(username, password, done) {

    await client.connect();
    const db = client.db(dbName);
    const collection = db.collection('usuarios');
    await collection.findOne({ usuario: username }, function (err, user) {


      if (err) { return done(err); }
      if (!user) { return done(null, false); }
      console.log(password);
      console.log(user.password);
      if (password!==user.password) { return done(null, false); }
      return done(null, user);
    });
  }
));


passport.serializeUser(function(user, done) {
  console.log(user);
  done(null, user.usuario);
});

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  res.render('login');
});

router.post('/registro', async function(req, res){

  regUser(req.body)

    .then(()=>{
      res.render('login',{info: "Registrado"})
    })
    .catch((err)=>{
      console.log(err);
    })
    .finally(()=>{
      client.close()
    })

});



async function regUser(datos){
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('usuarios');
  await collection.insertOne(
    {
      usuario: datos.usuario,
      password: datos.password
    }
  )
}

router.post('/login', 
  passport.authenticate('local', { failureRedirect: '/login' }),
  function(req, res) {


    res.redirect('/');
  });

module.exports = router;

    

> `enter code here`
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like to hash your password.

```
password = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
```

then check hash of both of the passwords, if both matches then you can allow user further like

```
const hashPassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 10)
const hashUserPassword = await bcrypt.hash(user.password, 10)
// and then do this to check if password same or not
if (hashPassword !== hashUserPassword) { return done(null, false); }
```

OR you can directly do this while inserting the password in db, this will put hash password in the db.

```
async function regUser(datos){
  await client.connect();
  const db = client.db(dbName);
  const collection = db.collection('usuarios');
  const hashUserPassword = await bcrypt.hash(datos.password, 10)
  await collection.insertOne(
    {
      usuario: datos.usuario,
      password: hashUserPassword
    }
  )
}
```

You can also have a look at this [link](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) to know more about bcrypt.

If issue still persists, let me know on comments.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, the thing is that I already tried to change it directly by inserting password hash in db but when I do this I can't log in anymore.

Comment: you have to update that in passport middleware too, everytime you have to get the hash of login password and check the condition.
`if (hashPassword !== hashUserPassword) { return done(null, false); }`
Specifically, I say this line
`if (password!==user.password) { return done(null, false); }`

Comment: or you can simply do this thing in passport middleware to check if both password matches or not 
`const pstatus = await bcrypt.compare(password, user.password)`

  `if (!pstatus) {console.log('incorrect password')}`